# Is there a word for writing and not looking at it (while writing)?

Tags: writing

"Writing while looking at something else" -- your hand is still moving, your writing is still legible, but your eyes are elsewhere, such as reading from the source material being copied.

Comment: 'Unsighted writing' ?

Answer (score 2):

With typing it is called "[**touch typing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_typing)". Now, writing predates typing, so it does not follow that the act would be called "*touch writing*", but absent a definitive answer to the contrary, I submit the term as a viable candidate :)

Comment: I don't think touch typing is directly comparable since you are still technically looking at what you're typing—on the screen (or paper, when typewriters were still in use). In any case, I did a brief search and didn't find anything that would suggest that "touch writing" (or "touch method" referring to writing) is used in this sense.

Comment: @laurel It isn't true that you are looking at what you are producing when you touch type. Touch typists originally typed up handwritten script or handwritten shorthand without taking their eyes off the the source document. I can't do this but my mother could. Also there are many former shorthand typists still working, so it's not that long ago that the skill was vital to business.

Answer (score 1):

It has been called *blind writing*:

> **Blind Writing**
>   Direct the students to close their eyes and write the letter five to ten times without looking. Without visual cues, the students must rely on muscle memory. Instruct the students to open their eyes and choose the letter which is written the most legibly.
>   [- Logic of English](https://www.logicofenglish.com/rhythm-of-handwriting-articles/handwriting-practice-ideas)

This usage is consistent with the following definition:

> **blind** *adjective*
>   1.1 (of an action, especially a test or experiment) done without being able to see or without having relevant information.
>   ‘If you are playing blind you do not look at your cards, but leave them face down on the table.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blind)